# Understanding Generics

Tags: java, generics, implementation

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "your_entity")
    public class YourEntityClass implements IEntity<Long> {

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "gen_test_entity2_id", sequenceName = "test_entity2_id_seq", allocationSize = 10)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "gen_test_entity2_id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 64)
        private String name;

        /*
         * Create constructors, getters, setters, isEquals, hashcode, etc.
         */
    }

public interface IEntity<I extends Serializable> extends Serializable {

    /**
     * Property which represents id.
     */
    String P_ID = "id";

    /**
     * Get primary key.
     *
     * @return primary key
     */
    I getId();

    /**
     * Set primary key.
     *
     * @param id primary key
     */
    void setId(I id);
}
```

For the above code, my question is, why `YourEntityClass` need to pass `Long` in `IEntity<Long>`? Why not something else like `IEntity<String>`? Is it because the `id` is of type `Long`, and the getter of `id` must return the same type which we provided to `IEntity`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`YourEntityClass` puts `<Long>` in `IEntity` arbitrarily. Any type that implements `Serializable` can go there.

After you've chosen the type for `I`, your `getId()` method has to return that same type.

for example you could have another class that implements `IEntity<String>` and `getId()` in that case would have to return a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The YourEntityClass is implementing a generic interface and it is specifying the specific type for generic interface.  It has a method using a specific type (Long) since that is what implementing that interface entails.